# /dev/shm & /proc hardening

Tags: linux, security, kernel

I've seen mention of securing /dev/shm and /proc and I was wondering how you do that and what it consists of doing? I assume this involves /etc/sysctl.conf editing of some kind right.

Like these?

```
kernel.exec-shield = 1
kernel.randomize_va_space = 1
```

Comment: For `/dev/shm`, I suppose you could disable it or restrict the permissions if you don't have any applications that require POSIX shared memory. But for `/proc` I can't think of anything you could do. That filesystem is actually quite vital for commands like `ps` to work. Do you have any references concerning such hardening practices?

Comment: Nope. I've just heard of them. I know with CloudLinux and GRSecurity Kernels, users can only ps their processes in /proc. Just not sure if you can do similar security on a default kernel.

Comment: Which version of Linux are you currently using?

Comment: 1 server CL. Another GRSec. and several others just use the default CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 11):

The process I use, based on the [CIS Linux Security Benchmark](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/show-single/?file=rhel6.100), is to modify `/etc/fstab` to restrict device creation, execution and suid privs on the `/dev/shm` mount.

```
shmfs        /dev/shm         tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec        0 0
```

For the sysctl settings, simply adding some of these to `/etc/sysctl.conf` works. Run `sysctl -p` to activate.

```
# CIS benchmarks
fs.suid_dumpable = 0
kernel.exec-shield = 1
kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the CIS Security Benchmark, every security conscious sys admin should read and apply the relevant recommendations.

Comment: How would you mount it? Is tmpfs the same as shmfs? I get tmpfs for /dev/shm

Answer (score 6):

ewwhite has already mentioned the CIS Linux Security Benchmark recommendations, I would also like to add another security guideline worth mentioning - [Guide to the Secure Conﬁguration of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/rhel5-guide-i731.pdf) by the NSA. In addition to adding `nodev,nosuid,noexec` options for /dev/shm, the recommendations for kernel parameters which affect networking are mentioned in section 2.5.1 -

Host only

```
net.ipv4.ip forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send redirects = 0
```

Host and Router

```
 net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0
 net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
 net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
 net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
 net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
 net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
 net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 0
 net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
 net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_messages = 1
 net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
 net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
 net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
```